# Using vue-resource in a plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, vue.js, vue-resource

I am trying to put all my vue-resource requests into a separate component/plugin for easy re-use and no duplication, but being new to Vue I am not sure if this is the correct approach.
It seems a little clumsy.

I want to be able to define all my resources in my plugin as well as be able to initialize new sessions and setup the Auth header globally. The following works but I am sure there is a better/cleaner way.

Would appreciate any guidance/advice on the better approach here.
Thanks

**Plugin - DataService.js**

Created an Init function to setup the global Auth header and then some other properties to store paths and options.

```
const DataService = {
    init : function(newsession) {
        this.session = newsession;
        Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = newsession;
    },
    userpath : '/api/users/',
    options: {emulateJSON: true},
};

DataService.install = function (Vue, options) {

Vue.prototype.$getUser = function (userid) {
    return this.$http.get(DataService.userpath + userid);
}

Vue.prototype.$saveUser = function (user) {
    return this.$http.post(DataService.userpath + user.id,{data: user},DataService.options);
}
```

}

**Vue Instance - account.js**

Note: I am first initializing my DataService to pass in the new session as well as call it as a Plugin (.use).

```
DataService.init(session_id);
Vue.use(DataService);


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        user: { id: null, username: null},
        session: { },
        processing: false,
        alert: "",
        warning: "",
    },

    computed: {

    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.loadUser();


    },
    methods: {
        loadUser: function () {
            this.$getUser(userid).then(function(response) {
                // get body data
                var res = response.body;
                this.user = res.data;
                this.session = res.session;

            }, function(response)   {
                console.error('Error loading user',response);

            });
        },
        saveUser: function () {
            this.$saveUser(this.user).then( function(response) {
                // success callback
                console.log('Saved user',response);
            }, function(response){
                // error callback
                console.error('Error Saving user',response);
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't attach those methods to the Vue prototype, instead you should use a [`mixin`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), which will allow you to import the methods when you need them. Also, it's now recommended that you use [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) rather than `vue-resource` as it been [officially retired](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4)

Comment: Thanks will look at axios. So I should do the same thing but just with a mixin instead of a plugin?
Any advice as to a better way to initialize the session as well as store the Auth header configuration?